# Best C++ RPC library for Windows/Visual Studio

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, rpc

I know this kind of question is asked a lot but I have a set of requirements:
1. Be able to compile and develop in Visual Studio on Windows.
2. Be somewhat modern - Async/threaded, clean.
3. C++

I've looked at thrift, messagepack, and even protobuf+RPC. All of them have massive issues in Windows.

FYI - I'm no pro programmer so asking me to apply out-dated patches to untested code is a pretty big ask. I know thrift has some patches available, but their >2MB big for old versions of thrift, with other patches thrown on top. God knows how well that'll work.

Comment: Protobuf is clean in Windows - what problems did you have?

Comment: Well protobuf is a serialization library. Great on its own, but, no RPC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you consider using Protobuf together with Boost asio? Of course it is not an RPC library, so that part you would have to do at your own, but it would be asynchronous and fast.

Comment: Its a possibility. I was just reading this blog article here on it: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/03/20/boost-asio-with-protocol-buffers-code-sample/

However I'm still looking for something a little more high level if at all possible. I'd like to have most of the socket programming abstracted away from me (endianness, etc)

Comment: Protobuf solves the endian problem. The only real "transport" you need to provide is length-encoding ahead of every protobuf frame, which is a single integer. Yes, its not RPC, but often message passing is superior.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ICE & proto buffer. since version 3.4.1, proto objects have been suported by ICE though there are some limits.